# MySQL Do I need to ROLLBACK a Transaction if no update has taken place

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, commit, rollback

I have the following stored procedure.

**My database engine is InnoDB and autocommit is on.**

In the final ELSE statement, do I need to provide a ROLLBACK; or will the ROLLBACK be made automatically once the stored procedure returns.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ApplyRoomPriceUpdate`(iRoomId INTEGER, dStartDate DATE, dEndDate DATE, dcPrice DECIMAL(10,4))

BEGIN
DECLARE iRoomCount INTEGER; 

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    -- ERROR
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT 1 AS 'ReturnCode', @p1 AS 'MySqlErrNo', @p2 AS 'MySqlErrMsg';    
    ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    -- WARNING
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT 2 AS 'ReturnCode', @p1 AS 'MySqlErrNo', @p2 AS 'MySqlErrMsg';    
    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT COUNT(RoomId) FROM Room WHERE RoomId = iRoomId INTO iRoomCount;

IF iRoomCount > 0 THEN

    UPDATE RoomDefault SET Price = dcPrice WHERE RoomId = iRoomId;

    COMMIT;

    SELECT 0 AS 'ReturnCode', NULL AS 'MySqlErrNo', 'Update applied' AS 'MySqlErrMsg';

ELSE
    -- FAILURE 
    SELECT 2 AS 'ReturnCode', NULL AS 'MySqlErrNo', 'Update failed' AS 'MySqlErrMsg';
    -- DO I NEED ROLLBACK HERE??
END IF;

END
```

Comment: It will not rollback when the procedure ends, so end your transaction to prevent it from staying open and potentially mess with any code that follows (that does not expect to be inside a transaction, e.g. "thinks" it's in autocommit mode). Also, more severely, unless you changed your default isolation level to `serializable` (or add `for update` to your select), your transaction currently has no effect: e.g. nothing prevents a second transaction from deleting the selected roomid between select and update. The code will behave the same with and without a transaction.

Comment: @Solarflare the tx_isolation is set to REPEATABLE READ.  So to confirm you are saying I need to set ROLLBACK; in the last ELSE ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `rollback` (or `commit`, as you did not change anything in that path) to end the transaction (and go back to autocommit mode), unless you do not do anything in this session after this (e.g. disconnect, which rolls back open transactions); and in this specific case, you might as well not use a transaction at all, as it has no effect here, although this might just be because this is not your complete code.